# Heroku PostgreSQL giving errors when using "<=" operator in where statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

Im creating a rails app with specials that expire. Every time  someone logs on, I have a Def that looks for specials who have already expired, and then delete then. It works fine locally, but when i deploy it to heroku, I get this error:

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying <= numeric
```

and the hint:

```
 HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Here is the def i've created. I added a before_filter in the application controller for the def

```
    def check_expired
    time = DateTime.now.to_f.to_s
    @specials = Special.where("expires <= #{DateTime.now.to_f.to_s}")
    @specials.destroy_all
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let Rails handle dates for you and do it like this

```
@specials = Special.where('expires <= ?', Time.zone.now)
```

or just...

```
@specials = Special.where('expires <= NOW()')
```